# How do I exclude Enum properties with EF4/CTP5 fluent mappings in a generic fashion?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-ctp5, ef-code-first

I am just diving into the use of code-first with CTP5 for Entity Framework. To ease the pain of configuring the database mappings I've created myself a little helper class to serve as the base class for any custom mappings, but I'm unable to figure out how to make the last statement in the method work.

I am locating all public properties of type Enum and then calling the .Ignore method for every property found on the given type. The code uses Fasterflect for reflection and a little ForEach helper, but it should be fairly obvious what the code does.

```
internal abstract class AbstractMappingProvider<T> : IMappingProvider where T : class
{
    public EntityTypeConfiguration<T> Map { get; private set; }

    public virtual void DefineModel( ModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        Map = modelBuilder.Entity<T>();

        Map.ToTable( typeof(T).Name );

        typeof(T).Properties( Flags.Public | Flags.Instance )
            .Where( p => p.PropertyType.IsEnum )
            .ForEach( p => Map.Ignore( e => p ) );
    }
}
```

Executing the above gives me the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 
The expression 'e => value(Domain.AbstractMappingProvider`1+<>c__DisplayClass3[Domain.User]).p' is not a valid property expression.
It must be of the form 'e => e.Property'.
```

How can I use the "p" (which is in fact a property on "e") to make this not just compile but also work? :o)

I'm hoping someone has a clever trick to solve this. Alternatives solutions are welcome, but remember that the whole idea is to avoid having to call Map.Ignore for every enumeration property.

Comment: I'm still looking for a working solution to this problem, as the answer given below merely is a pointer in the direction to take, but doesn't get into the nitty-gritty details of constructing the right expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the standard .NET reflection libraries but I'm sure you can convert it to fasterflect if you like. I've added an Ignore method to the AbstractMappingProvider so that we can use MakeGenericMethod() to resolve the generic type for the property at runtime in order to cast the Lambda we have at that point to the correct Expression type. There could well be a better/faster/easier way to do this.

As a side note, I'm fairly sure that in that the code first Release Candidate (part of the Entity Framework 4.1 release candidate), enums are already ignored by default when mapping by convention.

```
internal abstract class AbstractMappingProvider<T> : IMappingProvider where T : class
{
    public EntityTypeConfiguration<T> Map { get; private set; }

    public virtual void DefineModel(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Map = modelBuilder.Entity<T>();

        Map.ToTable(typeof(T).Name);

        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsEnum);

        var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");

        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            // Build up the expression
            var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, propertyInfo);
            var funcType = typeof (Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof (T), propertyInfo.PropertyType);
            var ignoreExpression = Expression.Lambda(funcType, propertyExpression, new[] {parameterExpression});

            // Call the generic Ignore method on this class, passing in the expression
            var ignoreMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("Ignore");
            var genericIgnoreMethod = ignoreMethod.MakeGenericMethod(propertyInfo.PropertyType);
            genericIgnoreMethod.Invoke(this, new object[]{ignoreExpression});
        }
    }

    public void Ignore<TPropertyType>(LambdaExpression lambdaExpression)
    {
        var expression = (Expression<Func<T, TPropertyType>>) lambdaExpression;
        Map.Ignore(expression);
    }
}
```

Comment: wow that did exactly what I needed. In fact, your side note might have sufficed (can't believe I just assumed it would break on seeing an enum property), but I'm very happy with also seeing what I should have written :)

Answer (score 1):

The problems is that P is a PropertyInfo object.  That class has metadata about the property but knows nothing about values assigned to the property on various objects.  You will have to manually create an Expression object to pass in to the Ignore method based by leveraging the property name that you can get from P.

Comment: Could you perhaps expand on that explanation with code sample?

Comment: @Morten, sorry I don't know a whole lot about working with Expressions... just enough to know that's what you need here :)

Comment: Buggers, as it's not exactly my strong side either. I can see that it wants an Expression<Func<T,TProperty>> but how to create that from my ingredients... :)  Hopefully someone else can shed more light on this.